# how to Update an empty table with the result of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table name average rating. i want to update my table name final rating with the result of this query

```
select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid
```

how can i do this?

[image: Take a look at image attached]

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Use UPDATE and set the values as the data from the SELECT statement

Comment: `INSERT INTO taget_table TABLE (select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid)` might work

Comment: Can you make query because i can't understand what you are saying
i tried this "INSERT INTO FinalRating (spid, rating)  
 select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid  "
but it duplicates complete data every time the querry executes

Comment: insert querry works but it duplicates the whole data present in table every time the querry executes

Comment: my mistake, if you want to update you just do an update statment with a join ill post answer in a second

Comment: yes please post the answer i'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
INSERT INTO FinalRating
select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid
```

or if the FinalRating table contains more information you could also specify the columns

```
INSERT INTO FinalRating (spid, rating)
select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid
```

you can also add a where clause to either query if you need a subset of data.

Edit: If this is not something that is one off and has to be run repeatedly the above solution would duplicate the data

in that case I recommend you merge the tables

```
Merge FinalRating AS TARGET using 
(select spid,AVG(avgRat) as averageRating from AvgRating group by spid) as SOURCE
on (Target.spid = source.spid)
WHEN MATCHED TEHN
UPDATE SET Target.rating = Source.averageRating
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
Insert (spid, averageRating)
VALUES(Source.spid, Source.averageRating)
```

Notice that I gave the AVG(avgRat) an alias so that I can reference it later

Comment: Insertion duplications the whole data every time query executes

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO FinalRating (select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid)
```

If you want to avoid dublicated just make sure spid is unique on the other table
should work

if you want to update you have to do a join something along these lines

```
UPDATE FinalRating TA 
INNER JOIN (select spid,AVG(avgRate) avg from AvgRating group by spid) as TB 
ON  TA.spid = TB.spid
SET TA.spid=TB.spid, TA.rating=TB.avg
```

**Edit:**
Have now checked this and should work perfectly fine, you have to run both to both insert and update if row already exists and Finalrating.spid has to be unique

Comment: it is unique in the other table but the problem is this everytime i run the inert query it copy all data including new data from previous data and add it to target table
for example: IF there are 2 rows present in final rating table a new record come querry will execute again this time it add 6 rows into final rating table instead of adding only new row to table

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Insert into FinalRating 
select spid,AVG(avgRat) from AvgRating group by spid
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation of what you've changed and why yours should work for other users.

Comment: @MarioCodes, I formatted the text for easy readability